# Moving couchdb 3.3.2 shards to another server

Tags: couchdb

I'm looking for a little help about moving shards folder from a server to another.
I'm supposed to move a web application that uses couchdb to another server but I don't find how to manage moving the databases into the new server.
I didn't install the original couchdb server so I can't say exactly how it has been configured and I'm a newbie with couchdb, but I've found some folders in the shards folder of couchdb that are containing the shards of the databases I need to move.

I found some documentation on internet who told to just copy the shards folders to the new server, I test it, but it's not working, I can't see the databases into Fauxton.

Permissions are alright on the targeted folders, I've controled on the default.ini and local.ini the database_dir.

Is there anyone who has been able to move the databases like this ?
FYI it's standalone servers, there is no cluster.

Thanks a lot for your help